# VBA sum function Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make an Excel document where you can select one of five possible products, and after you've done that, enter an ammount (positive or negative). This ammount is then summed to the corresponding product. However I have no idea how to do this in Excel-VBA.

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "summed to the corresponding product"? Do you mean that the product has a value, say gross sales, and you want a macro to add/subtract from that?

Comment: So you want to click on a cell, have it pop up an inputbox, have the user input an amount, and have the cell next to the cell clicked populate with that value?

Comment: @KFichter Jep I meant that the product has a value (in the next column) and that value should change by the value which is entered

Comment: @JNevill Yes that could be a suitable solution. However the values shouldn't be overwritten, but added or substracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty code that lets you add/subtract values (positive for add, negative for subtract). Add it to your file, then change the offset to match whatever cell holds the value you wish to add/subtract. You're going to have to select (make active) the product you want to change, then run the macro every time you want to add/subtract, but you could probably add a button or something if you want to make it easier.

```
Sub productValue()

Dim valueBox As Long

    valueBox = InputBox("Amount to add/subtract?")
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value + valueBox

End Sub
```

Comment: To make this trigger when a cell is clicked, you can use the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick()` or `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` event. Instead of sticking this in a seperate Module, you instead, in the VBAProject, stick it in the code for the particular sheet.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something obvious